# Is there a provision for saving the Questions and Answers to a folder?

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to save the pages directly into a folder so that it can be accessed later offline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not what you are after, but it is possible to save the entire page of questions and answers locally using your webbrowser using "save page as" (either the full page with pictures or only html text). I agree that a built-in download option at Stackexchange could be a useful feature though.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that that could be done. The other feature that is required is printing it if necessary. I mean the questions and answers and relevant things and not the whole page.